# openpyxlを使って、フィルターをしたい

Tags: python, python3, openpyxl

#### やりたいこと

Excelからデータを読み込みB列空白の場合だけデータを選択して
ブラウザで検索したいです。

現在下記のコードで、処理可能ですが
最初の行が読み込んでしまうので、すべて１行目から国が検索されます。
直前にB列が空白の場合、Japan、Brazilのデータから検索したいです。

**Excelのデータ:**

```
Country Flag      
America OK
Japan   
Argentina OK
Brazil
```

**実現したい内容**

```
pandasのように列を指定して直前にフィルターをしたいです。

#OKからフィルター外す
 df =df[df["Flag"] != "OK"]
 #print(df)

もしくはB列を空白選択

#空白のみを選択
  df= df[df['Flag'].isnull()]
```

**Excelのフィルター:**

```
Country Flag      
Japan   
Brazil
```

**Excelの結果:**

```
Country Flag      
America OK
Japan   OK
Argentina OK
Brazil  OK
```

コード

```
import openpyxl 
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

#エクセル読み込み
file_excel_r=r"C:\Users\test\Documents\test\test.xlsx"

#エクセルファイルを読み込み
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_excel_r)
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

#1行ずつ読み込み
#2行目からループを行う
for i in range(2,ws.max_row+1):
 
 options = Options()
 options.add_argument('--headless') 
 options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
 options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
     
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())

 #country
 country = ws['a'+str(i)].value

 #flag
 flag = ws['b'+str(i)].value

 #url指定
 url = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+country
 print(url)
 
 #検索サイトを開く
 driver.get(url)
 
 #2秒待機
 time.sleep(2)

 #B列が空白であればOKを記載
 if flag is None or not str(flag).strip():
        ws['B'+str(i)].value = "OK"
 else:
       print('空白なし')

 #エクセル保存
 wb.save(file_excel_r)

 driver.quit()
```

どのようにopenpyxlを使って、フィルターすれば良いでしょうか。
ご教授の程お願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

openpyxlには`pandas`のように柔軟な列フィルタで対象を抽出する機能はありません。
Excelのようにフィルタで[非表示設定](https://www.dfour.net/python-openpyxl-3/)にすることはできますが、お求めの機能ではないと予想します。
フィルタではなくif文での条件分岐のご利用を検討ください。

すべての国が検索される原因は、条件分岐せずに必ず`driver.get(url)`を呼び出していることです。
`#B列が空白であればOKを記載`するif文で既にお求めの条件分岐していますので、左記のif文の条件に合えば`#検索サイトを開`かないようコードを書き換えることで目的を達成できるかと存じます。

Comment: if分岐を前に持ってきて実現したい内容することできました。アドバイスありがとうございます。